# Swift Package Manager, target based dependency

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to get dependency target based in SPM, I have `Package.swift` defined here:

[image]

So I have `RxSwift` defined in package dependencies but it's **NOT** used in target `ReCaptcha` but only in target `ReCaptchaRx`

### What I expected to happen:

If I choose to select only one target without `Rx` I expected it to fetch only `ReCaptcha` dependency and ignore `Rx`.

[image]

### What actually happen:

After importing only `ReCaptcha` I'm getting package resolved **but unusable**, if I choose on import window `ReCaptchaRx` I'm getting as expected usable Rx what is fine. But why then SPM even fetching and resolving `RxSwift` in this case?

[image]

### Question

Why Xcode is resolving `RxSwift` on target that does not have a dependency to it? Can that be prevented? I would expect similar behaviour as with `AppSwizzle` in this example that if target is not used is not being resolved.

### Source code:

This is an open source library available here:
https://github.com/JakubMazur/ReCaptcha/blob/swift-package-manager/Package.swift

If you want to checkout this in SPM will resolve package from `https://github.com/JakubMazur/ReCaptcha` on branch `swift-package-manager`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, Swift Package Manager is not yet sophisticated enough to not resolve all transitive dependencies, even if they are exclusively used by a target you are not depending on.

While it is clutter that all transitive dependencies show in the Xcode sidebar package dependencies list, I do not believe it implies that your Demo app would actually ship with any of those unused targets/dependencies. It is only clutter in the sense that they show in that sidebar and that they are checked out in cache directories.

Slightly different: [as of SPM 5.2, SPM *is* smart enough to not download transitive dependencies only used by your dependencies' *test* targets](https://swift.org/blog/swift-5-2-released/#swift-package-manager). Perhaps one day this will be improved to cover the case you ask about as well.

Comment: Thanks, seems like this is not implemented yet. Following the links from your answer it's an open issue: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8658